# Reuse variables in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know is there a way to reuse variables defined as `AS` and not to rewrite our code every time or not?

`Example`

I have such line:

```
IFNULL((CASE WHEN (((c.gaji_pokok+c.tunjangan+q.jkk+q.jkm)*12)+('c.komisi' * 'c.thr') >= 6000000) then ((c.gaji_pokok+c.tunjangan+q.jkk+q.jkm)*12)+('c.komisi' * 'c.thr')*0.05 ELSE 6000000 end),0) as b_jabatan,
```

and the next time I need such command I just want to use `b_jabatan` instead of writing whole line

`example`

```
IFNULL((b_jabatan,0) as brutto_tahun,
```

**is that possible?**

Comment: You could declare it as a string variable and then use execute dynamic sql using string concatenation, but that would be ugly and messy I guess?

Comment: I want reuse (i.e.) `b_jabatan` in order to avoid my code being messy, I want make my code shorter and cleaner

Answer (score 0):

Use the `least()` function:

```
coalesce(least( ((c.gaji_pokok+c.tunjangan+q.jkk+q.jkm)*12)+(c.komisi * c.thr)*0.05, 6000000
              ), 0
        ) as b_jabatan,
```

Comment: i think you didn't close `coalesce(`

Comment: unknown column `b_jabatan` in list

Comment: @mafortis . . . There is no need to use `coalesce(b_jabatan, 0)`, because the value cannot be `NULL`.

Comment: @mafortis . . . The above code is based on your definition for `b_jabatan`.  That alias cannot be used in the same `select`.  You would need to use a subquery or CTE.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reuse an alias in the same scope - left apart the `order by` clause (and, in MySQL, the `group by` and `having` clauses).

You either need to repeat the expression, or use a subquery or CTE (which creates a new scode). So:

```
select t.*, coalesce(b_jabatan,0) as brutto_tahun, ...
from (
     select
          < your super long expression > as b_jabatan,
          ...
     from ...
) t
```